# Changing class constructor multiple properties with a single method JS

Tags: javascript, methods, properties

There is a similar question with this from almost 8 years ago but it doesn't have a clear answer for me.

I have a shopping cart constructor that it's like this:

```
class Carrinho {
    constructor(itens, quantidade, valorTotal) {
    this.itens = itens
    this.quantidade = quantidade
    this.valorTotal = valorTotal
    }
```

I want a Method to add item type and it's quantity to the resulting object. I thought on:

```
    addItem = function(itens, quantidade) {
    this.itens += itens
    this.quantidade += quantidade
```

This doesn't work though. Nor does 2 `return` lines. I've tried with object notation too `{}` but I wasn't successful. I also saw a similar way using `for (var itens in constructor) this.itens = itens` and it also didn't work.

What are the ways to do those? Or should I add multiple methods for ervery property?

Comment: That's not a method, it doesn't have access to `this`.

Comment: "*There is a similar question with this*" - please link it!

Comment: Please show us how you are calling the constructor and the method, in particular what values you are passing in. Is `itens` an array?

Comment: @Barmar It might be a class field (given the indentation, the lack of closing braces, and the lack of a declaration keyword). But you're right, it *should* be a method using the proper syntax.

Comment: `class Carrinho { constructor() {} addItem () {} }`

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Barmar noticed, my problem was declaring a method using a wrong syntax while inside the `class` operator. The correct code would be:

```
class Carrinho {
    constructor(itens, quantidade) {
    this.itens = itens;
    this.quantidade = quantidade;

    }
addItem(itens, quantidade) {
    this.itens += itens;
    this.quantidade += quantidade;
  }
}
```

Thank you very much for noticing it while also giving me directions on how to make better use of this collective!

Answer (score 0):

```js
class Carrinho {
  constructor(itens, quantidade) {
    this.itens = itens;
    this.quantidade = quantidade;

  }
  addItem = function(itens, quantidade) {
    this.itens += "," + itens;
    this.quantidade += quantidade;
  }
  valorTotal = function() {
    return this.itens.split(',') + " = total = " + this.quantidade;
  }
}
var c = new Carrinho("blue", 1);
c.addItem("red", 1)
console.log(c.valorTotal());
```

soory i have edit the méthod

Comment: This seems more sensible, but please use method syntax for methods.

Comment: your comment was helpfull for me to anderstand what to do best answer, thank Bergi

Answer (score -1):

Since `addItem` isn't a method of the class, it doesn't receive the object as `this`. You need to pass the instance as an explicit argument.

```
function addItem(carrinho, itens, quantidade) {
    carrinho.itens += itens;
    carrinho.quantidade += quantidade;
}

c = new Carrinho(1, 2, 3);
addItem(c, 5, 10)
console.log(c)
```

Comment: It is a method. The code is just separated from the rest of the class on this question because it is my main concern here.

Comment: Methods are not normally defined use `name = function()` syntax.

Comment: Thank you for noting this. This was the problem with the code: I tried defining the method using a wrong syntax. Inputing `addItem(itens, quantidade) {; this.itens += itens; this.quantidade += quantidade; }` made it work. I'm still very new to POO. Thank you very much for solving my problem!

Comment: Don't change the question to show the answer. If you want to show the solution, post it as an answer.

Answer (score -1):

```js
var addItem = function(itens, quantidade, boolean) {
    if (boolean) {
        addItem.itens = [itens];
        addItem.quantidade = [quantidade];
    } else {
        addItem.itens.push(itens);
        addItem.quantidade.push(quantidade);
        }
        }
        
        addItem(1, 1, true);
        addItem(1, 1);
        console.log(addItem.itens);
```

```js
var addItem = function(itens, quantidade, boolean) {
if (boolean) {
    addItem.itens = itens;
    addItem.quantidade = quantidade;
} else {
    addItem.itens += itens;
    addItem.quantidade += quantidade;
    }
    }
    
    addItem(1, 1, true);
    addItem(1, 1);
    console.log(addItem.itens);
```

in all case you have to initialise your variable